# document.querySelector return Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to retrieve an input value from my login screen and switch to my home screen.

I made a document.querySelector to access my login ID and saved this value in a const called empresa.

Inside my house I imported this constant and made a console.log to check if I was receiving the data while entering it into my setState so I get the Array position equal to the empresa number. But the value returns Indefinite.

I also get a Warning:

Warning: Failed prop type: Provided a value prop to a form field without an onChange handler. This will make a field read-only. If the field has to be changeable, use the default value. Otherwise, set onChange or read-only.

How can I solve this?

Login screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import {LoginService} from "../../services/LoginService"

import './loginPage.css'

//Recebe o número da empresa
export const empresa =  parseInt(document.querySelector("#empresa").value)


class Login extends Component   {

    
    
    fazerLogin  =   infosDoEvento   =>  {
        
        

        infosDoEvento.preventDefault();
          const dadosDeLogin    =   {
                login:  this.refs.inputLogin.value,
                senha:  this.refs.inputSenha.value,

        };
        console.log(dadosDeLogin)
        LoginService.logar(dadosDeLogin)
        .then(()    =>  {
                this.props.history.push("/home");
        })
        .catch(err  =>  {
                console.error(`[Erro    ${err.status}]`,    err.message);
        });
    }

    
    
   
    render() {
        return (
            
                <div className="loginPage">
                    <div className="container">
                   
                            <h2 className="loginPage__title">Seja bem vindo!</h2>
                            <form className="loginPage__form" action="/" onSubmit={this.fazerLogin}>
                                <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                    <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Login</label> 
                                    <input ref="inputLogin" className="loginPage__input" type="text" id="login" name="senha"/>
                                </div>
                                <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">
                                    <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="senha">Senha</label> 
                                    <input ref="inputSenha" className="loginPage__input" type="password" id="senha" name="senha"/>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <label className="loginPage__label" htmlFor="login">Empresa</label> 
                                    <input ref="inputEmpresa" className="loginPage__input" type="text"  id="empresa" name="empresa" />

                                </div>
                                <br></br>
                                <div className="loginPage__inputWrap">


                                    <button className="loginPage__btnLogin" type="submit">
                                        Logar
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                   
                    </div>
                </div>
         
        )
    }
}

export default Login;
```

Home screen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Container, Table} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Extrato from '../Extrato'
import NavBar from '../NavBar'

import {consultarResumo} from '../../services/Home/index'

//Importa o valor da Empresa
import {empresa} from '../Login/index'

//Imprime o valor da Empresa
window.onload = teste => {console.log(empresa)}


class Home  extends Component   {
    
    

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           
            empresaId: 0,
                nomeEmpresa: "EMPRESA UM S/A",
                cnpj: 0,
            
            dadosBancario: {
                banco: 0,
                bancoNome: "CONTA SIMPLES",
                agencia: 0,
                conta: 0,
                digitoConta: 0
    },
                saldo: 0
            
        }
        
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        
        //Consulta na API e busca a posição igual o valor da empresa
        consultarResumo().then(dados => this.setState(dados[empresa]))
        
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <Container>
        <NavBar></NavBar>   
           <br/>
            <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                        <th>{this.state.nomeEmpresa}</th>
                        <th>CNPJ: {this.state.cnpj}</th>
                        <th>Número do Banco: {this.state.dadosBancario.banco}</th>
                        <th>{this.state.dadosBancario.bancoNome}</th>
                        <th>Agência: {this.state.dadosBancario.agencia}</th>
                        <th>Conta: {this.state.dadosBancario.conta}</th>
                        <th>Digito da Conta: {this.state.dadosBancario.digitoConta}</th>
                        <th>Saldo: {this.state.saldo.toLocaleString("PT-BR", {style: "currency", currency : "BRL"})}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </Table>
                <Extrato></Extrato>
        </Container>
        )
    }
    
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: your input should have value property like: `<input ref="inputEmpresa" className="loginPage__input" type="text"  id="empresa" name="empresa" value={somevalue} />
`

Comment: I did as you said, now I returned an error: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at Module ../ src / View / Login / index.js

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code like this.

```
$(document).ready( function() {
export const empresa =  parseInt(document.querySelector("#empresa").value)
})
```